# Defining materials for a whole scene (file)

Tags: materials

I have the impression that materials are defined per object. Probably the reason why Blender keeps adding ".001" ".002" etc. to the material names. can anyone explain this automated nomenclature?

How can I set materials for a whole scene (in my case, a whole Blender file), so I can have a consistent list of material names (only set by me, not Blender) from which to choose for materializing objects?

**Put differently**: Is there a way of moving the material (creating) tab from the *object-specific section* (physics, constraints, particle etc.) to the *scene-specific section* (world, output, render, scene etc.)?

Comment: The materials can be re-used as often as you'd like. If the material isn't assigned to any object, then you probably want to add a fake user though, since otherwise it will be removed once you close Blender.

Comment: More succinctly, instead of creating a material each time, use the drop down to select one already in your blender project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Materials are conceptually associated with *users*. In order for a material to be persistently stored it either needs to be assigned to an object (a real user) or the *Fake User* option needs to be enabled for it. If neither is the case, then the unused material won't be saved. That is the reason why you're always creating materials linked to an object when using the user interface.

However this *doesn't* mean that a material can only be used for one object. You can assign a material to as many objects as you like, across different view layers and scenes.

---

**Creating a material**

A material can be created in the *Material Properties*. You will need to select or create a new material slot, then you can create a new material using the *New* button.

[image: Creating a material]

[image: A material]

Alternatively you can create a new material based on another material by clicking on the *New Material* icon shown below:

[image: New Material]

---

**Reusing existing materials**

Once you've created a material, it can be assigned to other objects. Select the object in the 3D view and choose a material from the dropdown list.

[image]

---

**Users and fake users**

Materials that are currently without any user will be marked with a zero in front of its name in the dropdown list. If you don't assign this material to an object or activate the fake user option (the shield icon marked in yellow), it won't be saved in your project.

[image: Dropdown]

If a material has multiple users, then a button with a number will appear. You can create a separate copy of the material for the currently active object by clicking on the button (marked in red).

[image: Fake user and number of users]

More information can be found in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/assignment.html).

Answer (score 0):

The shield looking icon when clicked creates a "fake user" which makes that material available in the file/scene even if it's not assigned to an object. The icon to the right of the shield will create a copy of the current material and automatically increment the name as it seems you're seeing with ".001".

[image]

Check out more on that here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/assignment.html